# Custom Outlook 365 Addin error: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: c#, visual-studio, office365, outlook-web-addins

I have created a custom addin for outlook 365 using Visual Studio which uploads emails as a document to Our domain server.
It is working fine locally, but when I am deploying it using Microsoft Admin Portal and try to access it in Outlook 365 it gives error.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://waconatm.officeapps.live.com/apc/trans.gif?969c114967d3f6390dc1d7d9d845a90f'
> from origin 'https://outlook.office.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
> requested resource.

Please suggest what could cause the issue!

Comment: Could you give an example of the code that's failing? Does the add-in fail only in Outlook Web App (OWA) or in Outlook for Windows/Mac as well?

Comment: Also, when does the error occur? Is there a particular functionality of the add-in that's not working, or is the add-in failing to launch? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for responding! On debugging, I got to know it was a problem with WebService I was calling.